# how to solve this android studio installation error?

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoQn1.png)

I have installed android studio then I have seen this that english is not being showed

Comment: Choose config -> Language Settings. Since this is non english, config is second left botton option

Comment: sry I cant find anything

Comment: From where did you download/install it?

Comment: from official android site